# flutter doctor : Permission denied

Tags: flutter, dart, github, terminal

I downloaded Flutter successfully, but when I want to execute the flutter doctor command or any other command related to Flutter, it is not executed and I get a problem that permission is denied

bash: /data/data/vn.vhn.vsc/files/home/flutter/bin/flutter: Permission denied

[This is a set of commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8hA2.jpg)

I know I'm trying it on the phone because I use Visual Studio on the phone as well

At first I installed it normally where I used the command :
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutte

Indeed, it has been downloaded without problems, but the only thing that is incapable of it is using it in any way whatsoever in terms of knowing the version or examining it through the flutter doctor command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First try to install flutter from below links.

For MacOS : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

For Windows : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows

Then make sure you have set the path environment variable correctly.

For MacOs : https://rshankar.com/add-path-variable-in-macos-for-flutter/

For Windows : https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-install-flutter/